# Python. Не работает парсер для Kijiji. Ошибка 400 Kijiji

Tags: python, парсер

Я пишу парсер для Kijiji. Мне нужно на нем залогиниться. Вот что я пробовал:

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
r_token = session.head("https://www.kijiji.ca/j-token-gen.json")
token = r_token.headers['X-Ebay-Box-Token']
payload = {
    "operationName":"loginUser",
    "variables":{
        "input":{
            "fraudToken": None,
            "targetUrl":"L2ItYnV5LXNlbGwvb3R0YXdhL2MxMGwxNzAwMTg1XjI1cGY0d1lZa0NnZGFaMnlVNjcvaXc9PQ--",
            "emailOrNickname": emai,
            "password": passord,
            "rememberMe": True,
            "xsrfToken": token
            }
        },
        "query": "mutation loginUser($input: LoginUserInput!) {\n  loginUser(input: $input) {\n    userId\n    message\n    statusCode\n    redirectUrl\n    boxToken\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}

r = session.post("https://www.kijiji.ca/anvil/api", data=payload,  headers={"content-type": "application/json"})
print(r)
```

Возвращает ошибку 400.
В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А что написано в r.text?

Comment: В r.text "'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Error</title>\n</head>\n<body>\n<pre>Bad Request</pre>\n</body>\n</html>\n'"

Comment: зачем в запросе символы перевода строки?

Comment: Без понятия. Они были в запросе, который клиент отправляет Kijiji в момент залогинивания.